# WinAPI CreateDialog Ressource not found error 0x715

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, embedded-resource

Like often, I post here after several hours of research and tries without any success

I have this old dll written in C. For the moment, it has no interface but I need to add a dialog box to it.

I work with VS2017 and tried the following :

Using VS2017 ressource editor, I added a dialog box (id : IDD_DIALOG_REPLAY, automatically defined to 101 in resource.h file by resource editor) and added the following code to create my dialog box :

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_LINK_CLASS | ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES | ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

HWND  hDialog = 0;
hDialog = CreateDialog(pSGL->hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG_REPLAY),NULL,WndProc);

if (!hDialog)
{
    char buf [100];
    wsprintf (buf, "Error x%x", GetLastError ());
    MessageBox (0, buf, "CreateDialog", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 1;
}

ShowWindow(hDialog, SW_SHOW);
```

Note 1 : The message loop is already present in another dll executed in the same thread

Note 2 : in a first time, I use a call back function WndProc which is pretty standard and which basically executes the DefWindowProc function

When I compile my dll (with ressource compilation verbose option set), I get the following messages :

```
1>Writing DIALOG:101,   lang:0x40c, size 452.
1>Writing AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT:101,    lang:0x40c, size 2.
```

When I open the binary of my dll in VS2017, I can see that there is a dialogbox id 101

=> The dialog box is actually present in my binary file.

But when I execute it, I get an error 0x715 : ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND and of course, the dialog box is not created.

Note : this happen, no matter if the dialog box contains controls or if it is empty

I have absolutly no clue why this is happening. Any help would be really welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Antoine

Comment: You're not initialising the `INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX` structure properly so if your dialog actually uses any of the common controls its creation will probably be failing because of that.

Comment: I changed this (I hope correctly) but that did not fix my problem. 
And once again, I have the problem even if my dialog box is empty.

Comment: `pSGL->hInstance` has the wrong value.

Comment: pSGL->hInstance contains the main exe hInstance. But just in case, I replaced it by GetModuleHandle(NULL) => Still the same error 0x715.......

And in any cases, setting hInstance to NULL calling CreateDialog should not prevent the window to be created

Comment: Setting it to NULL has the same result, it looks for the resource in the .exe file instead of the .dll file.

Comment: @Hans : Thanks for your reply but so, what should I take for hInstance in order it looks in the dll for the resources ?

Comment: Thank you so much @Hans. It was that. I used the dll hinstance and not the exe hinstance. I close the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,thanks to [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), I found the reason.
I was using the exe hInstance and so, the program was looking for the dialog box inside the exe and not inside the dll.

Changing the hInstance to the dll one fixed my issue.

Thanks again Hans

Comment: Hi @Jopich, thanks for sharing the root cause and the solution, you could also feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).